# Exact sequences of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules, sections over X minus a point, and splitting

Tags: sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $X$ be a (let's say irreducible) scheme, let $x$ be a closed point, put $U = X - \{x\}$. Let $0\to\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{G}\to\mathcal{H}\to 0$ be an exact sequence of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. If the exact sequence of sections over $U$ is split, is the original sequence of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules split? The case I am most interested in is when $X$ is projective.

Comment: No, why would a section of $\mathcal{G\to H}$ extends to $X$ ? Take $X=\mathbb{P}^1, x$ the point at infinity, then $0\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1)\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}\to \mathcal{O}_x\to 0$ splits if we restrict to $U$ because it is $0\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^1}\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^1}\to 0$. There are also counter-example a short exact sequence of vector bundles (take the Euler sequence over $\mathbb{P}^1$).

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a counter-example but couldn't think of one.